# JPA Query for collection map join table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, collections, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity classes USER and TRAININGROLE as below

USER(id,csl,fullname,email)           -> id - long, others String

TRAININGROLE(id,role)     -> role is String, id in Long

I have Session.java entity class like below

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;


    @JoinTable(name="session_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="session_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="trainingRole_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id")   
    @ManyToMany
    private Map<User, TrainingRole> users = new HashMap<User, TrainingRole>();

    private Date start;
    private Date end;
```

I have to query the Session class to find the users who have a specific training role for a particular session. So I will pass the session id and the trainingrole object to the querying method. The wrong query is below ..

```
    public final static String FIND_TRAINER_FOR_SESSION = "SELECT DISTINCT users " +    
                "FROM Session s join s.users users where( :trainingRole in elements(s.users) and s.id = :sid )";
    @Query(FIND_TRAINER_FOR_SESSION)
        List<User> findTrainersForSessions(@Param("trainingRole") TrainingRole trainingRole,@Param("sid") Long sid);
```

Please help me correct the above query to get the users who have a Specific training role for a specific session ..

One more thing .. I am using JPAReposotiry for the query ..

```
@Repository
public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Session, Long>{
}
```

Comment: What is "in elements(s.users)" ?! Invalid JPQL

Comment: I wanted elements(s.users) to access trainingrole value for each map entry.. I am not sure if its right or wrong .. currently the above query is giving wrong result . I just wanted to know how to match the trainingrole  value to get the corresponding users

Comment: "elements" is not a JPQL keyword, so its invalid. "s.users" is a Map, so if wanting to access key you use KEY(...) and if wanting to access value then you use VALUE(...). Consult a JPQL reference

Comment: like this??         public final static String FIND_TRAINER_FOR_SESSION = "SELECT DISTINCT users " +  
   "FROM Session s join s.users users where( :trainingRole in value(s.users) and s.id = :sid )";

Comment: Exception :: "value" invalid identifier . .Used elements(s.users) and exception gone .. but still I am not getting the users

Comment: The query is now like this .     =>   public final static String FIND_TRAINER_FOR_SESSION = "SELECT index(users) " +  
   "FROM Session s join s.users users where ( :trainingRole in elements(s.users) ) and s.id = :sid ";                      But now the condition is wrong As it is not filtering anything based on trainingrole